# Cutting 1D list into two parts in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, select

I have two one-dimensional lists `x` and `y` (unknown huge length) taken from a data table.

I want to take the values of `x < 5` and corresponding `y` values into one `set` of lists, say `{x1, y1}`.

Also I want the values of `x > 6` and corresponding `y` values into another `set` of lists, say `{x2, y2`}.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you say a bit about what you have tried?

Comment: for example an array x has 1000 values from 0 to 10 and the array y has corresponding values. Now I want one array x1 (from x) which has values from 0 to 5 and and another x2 which has values ranging from 6 to 10 and the corresponding values in y1 and y2.

Comment: `array`s don't exist in Python. They are called `list`s instead (edit made)

Comment: a really cool thing with questions like this is to provide a sample input and a sample output, so that people can immediately grasp what's needed and what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option

```
z = zip(x,y)  #z = [(x[0],y[0]), ...]

smaller = [(xval,yval) for (xval,yval) in z if xval<= 5]  #those with x<=5
larger = [(xval,yval) for (xval,yval) in z if xval>=6]    #those with x>=6

x1,y1 = map(list,zip(*smaller))   #break them apart and make the results lists, not tuples.

x2,y2 = map(list,zip(*larger))
```

It's kind of cool how `zip(*list)` undoes `list = zip(.,.)` .   Note that there is a bug in this code if `x=5.5` is an option.  It would be better to put it as xval>5 for the larger case, but I haven't done that since it's not clear from your question what the criterion should be for 5.5.

Comment: fixed --- they were supposed to be x and y.  I'm also changing x and y in the list comprehensions to be xval and yval to avoid confusion with x,y.

Comment: Note - this assumes the entries are ints.  If you've got an x of 5.5, then it won't show up in x1 or x2.

Comment: but all of my values are float...and I want 5.5 to excluded

Comment: See the last sentence I put into my solution when I edited 3 min ago.  It's easy to deal with, just changing the `>=` or `<=` parts.

Comment: I got it. it works perfectly fine, thanks a lot. What the code does is that it excludes all the data between 5 and 6, exactly what I needed.

Comment: If the only thing you need to do is exclude the ones between 5 and 6 and you don't actually need the separate lists, then you can make `remaining = [(xval,yval) for (xval,yval) in z if xval<= 5 or xval>=6]` instead of creating `larger` and `smaller` and the code will run in about half the time.